# C# WebServices and Flex RPC Session doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, apache-flex, flex3

look im facing a problem. I have .NET + Flex application.

I have a component in Flex who uploads a .XLS file to the server. 
This component has a `Progress Bar`and it updates its bar and the Label with the `fileref.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);`

```
private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{   
    uploadProgress.label = "Uploading File %3%%";
    uploadProgress.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);
}
```

I used the FileReference and all the things to acomplish this. I save the posted file in the server with something like this

```
HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
string path = string.Empty;
string sFile = Request.Params["Name"];
if (uploadedFiles.Count != 0)
{
   HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[0];
   if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
   {
     path = Server.MapPath(".\\Uploads\\") + sFile;
     userPostedFile.SaveAs(path);
   }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, my bar and my label are refreshed ok, and my file is uploaded in a Temp folder and everything is ok, so going back to Flex I can listen when the file was uploaded through the `DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA`.
So When this event is dispatched I call a WebMethod of My WebService to Read that posted File and iterate over all the records. The file could have 65,000+ rows. So the info is updated row by row in a Oracle DB in some tables.

**What I'm trying to archieve is to have the same effect when the File is posted to the server. I want to have a progress Bar and show the % of rows uploaded to the Oracle DB.**

So what I Did in Flex was something like this:

```
//Service is the WebService Instance
ShowPopUpProgress();
Service.wsUploadFileToDb(FileName);     
Service.wsUpdatePercentage();

protected function wsUpdatePercentage_result(event:ResultEvent):void
{           
    compProgress.uploadProgress.label = "Uploading to DB %3%%";
    compProgress.uploadProgress.setProgress(event.result.Actual,     event.result.Total);
    if(event.result.Actual  !=  event.result.Total)
    {
    Service.wsUpdatePercentage();
    }
    else
    {
         RemovePopUpProgress();
    }
}
```

And in C# I did this

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
public void wsUploadFileToDb(string fileName)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Total"] = 0;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Actual"] = 0;
    //... And in the Loop
     HttpContext.Current.Session["Total"] = myDataTable.Rows.Count;
      for (int i = 0; i < myDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)                   
      {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["Actual"] = i + 1;
      }

}



 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Percentage ))]
    public Percentage wsUpdatePercentage()
    {
     Percentage oPercentage= new Percentage ();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Total"] != null)
        {
            oPercentage.Total = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["Total"]);
            oPercentage.Actual= Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["Actual"]);
        }
    }
```

I dont know if at This point you  understand what I want to do. I dont know if this is the best way, or there is another way to archieve my goal. But thats what I have so Far. And for some reason this is not working, The Session variables are stored correctly in the
    wsUploadFileToDb method but i Can't see them in the wsUpdatePercentage, they just dont "share" the session. I debugged both methods and the session ID is different. So The session is not being shared. I dont know what else to do. My First page in the Site is an aspx.. I put a dummy variable in session, because i read in one post that you had to do it, to start the session in the webservices but still not luck.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest an alternative approach; instead of trying to share the session information between the web app and the service it would be easier if you maintain a separate table which holds the information about the progress of data upload to the Oracle DB.

Basically you will be updating this table for every row that is inserted into the table from the excel, and from the service you can read the information from this progress table to report it to the flex client.

This way, you also have an audit log of all the uploads you have done from excel files to the database and information about if they succeeded properly and the count of rows that were imported.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking on that at first time, but I dont wanted to slow even more the process. But I didn't see it in that context, having an audit log. Let me have a try, and check the performance of it. Thanks.

Comment: I did it this way and it worked good, it doesn't resolve the problem about the session... but it resolves the problem. Thanks :D